# Exclude a directory from loading in a web project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, vs-web-site-project

We have a CMS site, where the user has uploaded a lot of content into the `content` directory of the site, for a lot of articles.

It takes a really long time to open this project because of loading all these sub-directories (one per article).

Is there any way to tell Visual Studio ***NOT*** to load a particular directory in the site? This directory has no code files in it, and nothing I would want to edit as part of development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is a "Web Site" project with no .csproj file, you may have to set the folder to *Hidden*.

Visual Studio does not load hidden folders.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1179077.aspx/1